# NLog: Format loglevel with Whitespaces

Tags: format, whitespace, nlog

I am using NLog for logging. 
Currently my Layout-String is:

```
"${date:format=dd.MM.yyyy HH\\:mm\\:ss,fff} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${message}"
```

This results in the following Logs:

```
18.12.2013 11:23:14,834 | INFO | this is an info
18.12.2013 11:23:14,835 | TRACE | this is a trace
```

What I want now is to format the "$level" to fill up with Whitespaces so that it looks like a table with 5 Characters.

I would like to have:

```
18.12.2013 11:23:14,834 | INFO  | this is an info
18.12.2013 11:23:14,835 | TRACE | this is a trace
```

I didn't find anything sadly... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try using the PaddingLayoutRendererWrapper.  I'm not sure where a good config example is, but the source in NLog's source repository is located here, so maybe you can reverse engineer the correct configuration:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/LayoutRenderers/Wrappers/PaddingLayoutRendererWrapper.cs

I think you would do something like this:

```
"${date:format=dd.MM.yyyy HH\\:mm\\:ss,fff} | ${padding:padding=5,fixedlength=true:${level:uppercase=true}} | ${message}"
```

Hopefully, that example will pad all log level values with 5 spaces on the left and then trim to an absolute length of 5.

`padding=5` means to add 5 padcharacters (default is `' '`) to left (negative means pad on right)

`fixedlength=true` is a boolean that indicates that the padded result should be trimmed to a maximum length of "padding" (i.e. 5 in my example)

Comment: Thank you! Padding was the word I'm looking for :-) With your hints I found it out - it's even more simple: ${level:uppercase=true:padding=-5} does it :-)

Comment: As for 2017, the LayourRenderer name is changed from ${padding} to ${pad}. Besides that, everything works

Comment: In case anyone else is searching for an example I wanted to add this example. Note: fixedlength causes an error.  ${pad:padding=-25:inner=${date:format=MM/dd/yy HH\:mm\:ss fff}}  ${pad:padding=-8:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}  ${pad:padding=-25:inner=${logger}}  - ${message}

Comment: @dgxhubbard The separator is ':', so this will work ${pad:padding=25:fixedlength=true:inner=${logger}}

Comment: @Jeroen Oh, thanks for pointing out, the comma there `padding=5,fixedlength=true`, impossible to see it, finally replaced it with `: ` and now works.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer since it isn't correct (anymore?). The [answer by stil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71879068/8521) is much cleaner and actually works using latest nlog.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2022, use the following:

```
${level:uppercase=true:padding=-5}
```

Example:

```
2022-04-15 03:04:58.0764 | INFO  | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler | AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was challenged.
```

If you want to align right, use `5` instead of `-5`.

Reference: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Pad-Layout-Renderer