# NLog not preserving whitespace

Tags: c#, xml, string-formatting, nlog

I'm trying to configure NLog for my C# application. I've got the logging working but it seems to have a mind of it's own in regards to whitespace. Here is my `NLog.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >

  <variable name="brief" 
            value="${longdate} | ${level} | ${logger} |: ${message}" />
  <variable name="verbose" 
            value="${longdate} | ${machinename} | ${processid} | ${processname} | ${level} | ${logger} |: ${message}" />

  <targets>
    <target name="myLog" xsi:type="File" fileName="myLog.txt" layout="${verbose}" />
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${brief}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="myLog" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The log's output currently looks like this:

> 2016-05-19 12:08:00.0302|DEBUG|Namespace.ClassName|:Some log message here...

For some reason, NLog is getting rid of the spaces I defined in the `target`'s `layout` attribute. What I would like the log entry to look like is:

> 2016-05-19 12:08:00.0302 | DEBUG | Namespace.ClassName |: Some log message here...

**How do I get NLog to preserve the spaces in the `layout` attribute?**

I've also tried to set the `level` to a fixed length with padding like this: `${padding:padding=5,fixedlength=true:${level:uppercase=true}}` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20666574/4416750), but still no luck.

Comment: Is this happening in both the file and console output?  What version of NLog are you using?

Comment: @Amy Yes it is happening in both the file and the console. I'm using the most current version (4.3.4) from the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/).

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce using that version and your configuration.  If you create a fresh project and use this configuration, does it happen there too?

Comment: @Amy I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @Amy Well there is something up with my code...not sure what but I was able to get a brand new project to work with NLog without issue...yet the issue persists in my current project. Oh well, guess I just need to keep digging. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that NLog doesn't play nice when there is a `#` character in the path for the solution. Renamed the path and it started working again.